# Monitor being shown as 'default' in settings with incorrect resolution & refresh rate

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, display-resolution

I just installed Xubuntu 16.04 on my computer along side Windows 10 (which I have had for the past couple of months, working great).

When ever I tried to boot into Xubuntu (when installed (now) or the installation environment on my bootable USB drive), nothing would show up on the monitor and it would go to sleep after I selected something from GRUB. I plugged my monitor into the port on my motherboard from my GPU and changed display output from `Auto (PCIE)` to `IGFX` in UEFI/BIOS, and it worked flawlessly, full QHD. I installed the OS, and in 'Additional Drivers', I changed from open source to the listed nVidia driver, then rebooted to UEFI/BIOS, set my display back to `PCIE`, plugged my monitor back into my graphics card, and was able to boot into Xubuntu, but the resolution was clearly off. I opened display settings, and found that instead of `Ancor Communication Inc 25"` (what it display when running off of iGPU), it simply said the monitor was `default`, with a resolution of 1024x768 and a refresh rate of 76.0 Hz (neither specs of my actual monitor). I am not able to change either of them, either through settings or with the `xrandr` command I've seen listed as a possible solution (I get `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default` whenever I try to run that). I opened 'Settings Editor' and was able to see the `Ancor Communications Inc 25"` monitor listed  as `active`, but not in the 'Display' setting. I then tried to manually download the driver form nVidia's website, and I got an error about incorrect UTF-8 (or something like that, I don't remember). I wasn't able to find anything like this online, so that brings me here.

Specs:

- Graphics card: Gigabyte GTX 970 Xtreme Gaming
- Monitor: Asus PB258 (2560x1440 @ 60Hz)
- OS: Xubuntu 16.04
- nVidia driver: NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.39 from nvidia-375 (proprietary, tested)

If you need any other information, I will do my best to provide it.

---

What I want is to be able to use my monitor like how I was able to in Windows or how it worked with the iGPU (but with my 970).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I resolved the issue:

1. Open UEFI and disable GPU in favor of iGPU
2. Boot into Linux and change to nVidia driver
3. Reboot into UEFI
4. Re-enable GPU
5. Reboot